# Angular2 Eclipse: HTML editor in Eclipse Oxygen shows errors from TypeScript

Tags: eclipse, angular, typescript, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-oxygen

I have installed the [Angular2 Eclipse](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/angular-eclipse) plugin for Eclipse Oxygen.
I have created an angular2 project with the angular CLI and then opened the project in eclipse.

I tried to convert the project to an Angular project, but when I right-click the project and go to configuration there is no such option. the only option is "Configure and detect nested projects.." which opens the import wizard.

When I open html template files in src/app/... e.g. my databinding.component.html,
the HTML editor shows ugly errors:

[image: errors in html editor]

When I hover over the errors I see that all have the format:

```
[ts] <error message>
```

some examples:

```
[ts] Cannot find name 'aNumber'. Did you mean 'Number'?
[ts] Cannot find name 'innerText'.
[ts] Cannot find name 'h4'.
```

But the errors are incorrect. I can start the app with ng-serve without problems.

How can I configure eclipse so that these false error messages disappear?
Thanks :)

**edit#1**

here is my eclipse typescript configuration, I don't see what I could change here..

[image: preferences]

Comment: I know I could possibly disable all validators for html files, but that's not a clean way to do it. And maybe even that would not fix it, because the messages come from [ts]

Comment: The errors are coming from Typescript intellisense in eclipse.Check if you have correctly configured typescript compiler with Eclipse.

Comment: I have updated my question. what is the correct configuration so the errors dont show up in html files? Note: There is no TypeScript Option in the root level of Preferences in my eclipse.

Comment: Yes it's a bug which is known. See https://github.com/angelozerr/angular-eclipse/issues/97 we must just be patient that TypeScript provides feature to fix it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As @Angelo mentioned, this bug is known and there is a temporal workaround.

You need to go to this file `C:\Users\MyUser\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\ts.repository\repositories\2.4.1\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsserver.js` and chage this part of code:

```
    Session.prototype.getDiagnosticsWorker = function (args, isSemantic, selector, includeLinePosition) {
        var _a = this.getFileAndProject(args), project = _a.project, file = _a.file;
        if (isSemantic && isDeclarationFileInJSOnlyNonConfiguredProject(project, file)) {
            return [];
        }
        var scriptInfo = project.getScriptInfoForNormalizedPath(file);
        var diagnostics = selector(project, file);
        return includeLinePosition
            ? this.convertToDiagnosticsWithLinePosition(diagnostics, scriptInfo)
            : diagnostics.map(function (d) { return formatDiag(file, project, d); });
    };
```

into this one:

```
    Session.prototype.getDiagnosticsWorker = function (args, isSemantic, selector, includeLinePosition) {
        var _a = this.getFileAndProject(args), project = _a.project, file = _a.file;
        if (isSemantic && isDeclarationFileInJSOnlyNonConfiguredProject(project, file)) {
            return [];
        }
        if (ts.fileExtensionIs(file, ".html") &&
            project.getExternalFiles && project.getExternalFiles() && project.getExternalFiles().map &&
            !ts.contains(project.getExternalFiles(), file)) {
            return [];
        }
        var scriptInfo = project.getScriptInfoForNormalizedPath(file);
        var diagnostics = selector(project, file);
        return includeLinePosition
            ? this.convertToDiagnosticsWithLinePosition(diagnostics, scriptInfo)
            : diagnostics.map(function (d) { return formatDiag(file, project, d); });
    };
```

Comment: I accept this answer, but for Angular (and other languages) I switched to Visual Studio Code anyway^^